# SDL can't create a array of rectangles without a constant variable

Tags: c++, sdl

I am working in **C++ SDL lib**. And I am trying to dynamically create a number of rectangles. But it doesn't work. The only solution I found over searching stackoverflow.com been to create a constant value, which I don't want to.

Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
void lvl001(){
max_score = 20;
count_enemies = 2;
SDL_Surface *enemie;
SDL_Rect enemies_sources[no] , enemies[no];

enemie = SDL_LoadBMP("player.bmp");

for( int count = 1; count <= no ; count++ ){
 enemies_sources[count].x = 0;  
}
}
```

**And one more thing**. If there would be an solution to this, then how  should I proceed if I want to blit it (`SDL_Blit...`)?

Comment: "[…] to create a constant value, which I don't want to." – Why do you not want to?

Comment: zenith. Because i a trying to create a game and the void you see is part of my first level .Should i redefine the rect every time i create a next level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, dynamic arrays are created using `std::vector<T>`, and looped through using the range-based `for` when you don't care about the indices:

```
std::vector<SDL_Rect> enemies_sources(no);
std::vector<SDL_Rect> enemies(no);

for (auto& source : enemies_sources)
{
  source.x = 0;
}
```

Comment: @electric-web For example [`SDL_BlitSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface).